# how to format a gridview field to display a rate ex.: 4/5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview populated by some text elements.  I am asking the user to put a rate from 1 to 5.  I will like to display the rate in the gridview like this  ex.: if the user select 4 then in the gridview field it will be display as 4/5.  I stored the rate 4 in a database field as a INT.

Here is the code behind

```
SqlConnection con = new 
    SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

//======= Insert Query.

string cmdText = "INSERT INTO Comments VALUES (@comment,@user,@rate, @date)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

//===== Adding parameters/Values.

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", txtComment.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtSignature.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", lstbxRating.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);

if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    con.Open();
}
int nbrRecords = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();

if (nbrRecords >= 1)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
}
```

the code .aspx

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="comment" HeaderText="comment" ReadOnly="True" 
             SortExpression="comment"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user" HeaderText="user" ReadOnly="True" 
             SortExpression="usager" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rate" HeaderText="rate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="rate"
            />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="date" 
            />
   </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the column property of GridView.
Put

```
DataFormatString="{0:0/5}"
```

In the field for rate.

Further more. If you can put the html markup of

```
<app:GridView..........>
```

I can show you where to add this code.

Just replace your aspx code with:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="comment" HeaderText="comment" ReadOnly="True" 
         SortExpression="comment"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="user" HeaderText="user" ReadOnly="True" 
         SortExpression="usager" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="rate" HeaderText="rate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="rate" DataFormatString="{0:0/5}"
        />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="date" 
        />
```

it will work, I already tested and it is working fine.

Comment: @lqbal  I got a parse error  Literal content ('<asp:BoundField DataField="cote" HeaderText="cote" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="cote DataFormatString="{0:0/5}"" />') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.

Comment: @lqbal maybe it should be save as a text field in the db ?  or convert when I store it  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", lstbxRating.Text);

Comment: I treated your rate filed as Integer

Comment: use this <asp:BoundField DataField="rate" HeaderText="rate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="rate" DataFormatString="{0:0/5}" />

Comment: @lqbal  How to fix this issue then ?  If I changed the save to the DB like this cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cote", Convert.ToInt32(lstbxRating.Text));

Comment: This line was ok cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", lstbxRating.Text); it will convert automatically when writing to db. Be sure that the field type in your table is 'int'

Comment: @lqbal  I cannot compile  got the error Error 1 Literal content ('<asp:BoundField DataField="cote" HeaderText="cote" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="cote DataFormatString="{0:0/5}"" />') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'. C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Examen2Q2\Default.aspx 23

Comment: there are to mistakes you are doing. see the extra " (double quote) after {0:0/5}" and you wrote {0:0/5}"" this cause error. Next you are using 'cote' before it was 'rate'

Comment: @lqbal  Thanks it works sorry for the errors....    Would you know how to put a fix length on the field Comment?  it is 255 characters field long.  I will like to have it display on multi-lines in the gridview and be smaller because right now it takes almost all the page?

Comment: please put a separate question for that. Unfortunately I am leaving now. and thanks as you accepted, if you may also vote, i can make century :P